# FLV Player Skin Custom URL

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, banner-ads, flvplayer

I have a flash banner ad (AS3) which uses a FLV Player component for a remove video. The Skin exports it's own SWF file for user with the video controls as I'm sure anyone familiar with Flash knows.

Is there anyway to specify where this file is remotely? I have to provide 1 file to my advertiser, and do not want to have to create custom video controls for this. Is it possible to upload this swf file to a remote location and tell Flash to pull it from there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using the actual FLV component, you would use the `skin` property

> A string that specifies the URL to a skin SWF file. This string could contain a file name, a relative path such as Skins/MySkin.swf, or an absolute URL such as http://somedomain.com/MySkin.swf.

e.g.

```
vidPlayer.skin = "http://youdomain.com/skin.swf";
```

If you're going to go that route, you need to setup a crossdomain.xml file on that server that is hosting the skin so whoever is making the request to load the skin swf is allowed.

I did banner creations for a little while and I remember the strict file size limits and the one file thing. I ended up hosting a lot of the content on remote servers too.